# sql script to insert mutliple rows

Tags: sql

Imagine I have a table like so in sql server 2012

```
Id | type | binary
1    1      FFX09
1    2      HY6Z0
2    1      TY67D
2    2      RTY7S
3    1      3YDH8
3    2      383JD
3    3      4HED8
```

What I would like to do is insert a new row for each id that doesn't have a corresponding type 3. It will add with the same id, type = 3 and binary will take the value from the type 2 row for that id.

I could do it in loop but wanted to know if there was a set based way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking, but based on your title, you might wanna take a look at this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use case of an `insert select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT  id, 3, binary
FROM    my_table t_outer
WHERE   type = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM   my_table t_inner
                                 WHERE  type = 3 AND t_inner.id = t_outer.id)
```

Comment: Great thanks, was missing an and in the not exists select but worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT DISTINCT id, 3, (SELECT binary FROM mytable mt2 WHERE mt.id=mt2.id AND type=2)
    FROM mytable mt
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE type = 3)
```